# Python : passing a variable created using eval in a file as a parameter of another function in another file

Tags: python, flask, eval

I am currently trying to build a web application using Flask in Python.

To make it easier, I will describe the problem with only two python files, f1.py and f2.py.

The first file f1.py in module mod1 is :

```
from mod2.f2 import function

vars()['x'] = []
eval('x').append(1)
print('f1 : ')
print(eval('x'))
function(eval('x'))
```

The second file f2.py in module mod2 is :

```
def function(x):
    print('f2 : ')
    print(x)
```

The output of f1.py is :

```
f1 : [1]
f2 : None
```

Therefore, x in f1 has the right value but None when passed to function.

Do you have by any chance a way to solve this issue ?

Thank you in advance for your help !

Comment: Are you sure you want to be using `eval` in a web application?

Comment: Functions don't know and don't care how you created an object, whether it was eval or not is irrelevant.  This MCVE is bogus.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this behavior, after actually running these files (not using `mod1` and `mod2` packages, but that shouldn't matter). Running `python f1.py` prints out what you'd expect.

Comment: As an aside, I highly question the decision to use eval. There is almost certainly a better way,

Comment: In the web application, I have to let the user define some variables and their types. Therefore, I have to get the output in strings, which explains (maybe I am wrong and there is a better alternative) the use of eval.